# Three instances of each openCV 3.1.0 library

Tags: c++, opencv

I was able to install and build openCV following the instructions here (http://charliegerard.github.io/blog/Installing-OpenCV/). But after successfully creating the dynamic libraries I noticed in the lib directory there are 3 instances of *each* library named in the following format:

libopencv_LibName.3.1.0.dylib

libopencv_LibName.3.1.dylib

libopencv_LibName.dylib

[Screenshot of the libraries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fsfXq.png)

My next step is to single out only the header files and libraries I need for my project, and I'm not sure if I really need all 3 instances of every library in use. Why does make create all these extras? And which ones do I need?

**Additional Info:**

OS: OSX El Capitan

IDE: Xcode 7.3.1

Comment: I'm going to guess that all the files other than *3.1.0.dylib are symlinks.  Otherwise, the files should be binary identical.  Is either true?

Comment: How do I check if they're binary identical? I tried opening it using a text editor but it is a bunch of question marks for the most part. @RobertPrévost

Comment: You can just use `diff`.

Comment: Actually I just noticed that there are tiny arrows right next to the library icons other than the *3.1.0.dylib libraries (updated the post with a screenshot). So I assume you are correct that the other two are possibly symlinks. Does this mean I can safely ignore them and just use the main one? @RobertPrévost

Comment: You probably should keep all of them and link to the one without the version number (see [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/475/how-do-so-shared-object-numbers-work) for more explanation).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you build the opencv library it creates the actual *.dylib binary (libopencv_LibName.3.1.0.dylib) that contains the release, the major, and minor version. (Release = 3, Major = 1, Minor = 0). This allows you to have a dynamic style of linking to a specific version of the library. (For example, opencv often is not completely compatible between release versions. (From 2.x.x to 3.x.x), however it often is compatible between major/minor versions.(3.0.x to 3.1.x) )

By linking to the 3.1.0 version, you are locking in on requiring that specific version of the libary. (If you update opencv, it will still be using openCV 3.1.0).

However if you link to the 3.1 version, it is only caring about the Release and Major version, but will allow minor version updates. (Currently the 3.1 is a symlink to 3.1.0, but if you installed 3.1.1, it would now reference the 3.1.1 library.) I generally find it best to link to this one as it will allow you to update for bug fixes, but will not break any functionality.

Finally there is the version-less symlink, this one will always reference the latest version of opencv you have installed. Currently it references 3.1.0, but if you installed 3.1.1 it will now reference 3.1.1. This would not be bad, but if you were to install 4.0.0, it would now be referencing this binary and likely break some of the API.

Comment: To clarify, does this mean that these libraries are independent of each other and that I do not need all 3?

Comment: @Gela: Yes, they are symlinks or shortcuts to the same file. The arrow you noticed, tells you that. Also, if you build opencv with opencv_world, you will have lib_opencv_world.3.1.0.dylib as well. This library contains everything( libcore, libimgproc, libcallib, etc.. )

Comment: Thank you. I used the prebuilt binaries on Windows and used opencv_world300.lib there but since there were no prebuilt binaries for Mac, I had to build the source myself and ended up with separate libraries. Do you know how I can get the same opencv_world library in Mac? That would actually be the ideal solution for me since I am building the same exact project on multiple platforms. @saurabheights

Comment: @Gela: Although there are no pre-built binaries for Mac, brew provides it. Install brew and run `brew info opencv`. Run and READ it. A simple command would be `brew install opencv --with-java --without-python`. Next, for install opencv world, AFAIK brew does not supports it. If you are using cmake/ ccmake, it has BUILD_OPENCV_WORLD option which needs to be turned ON.